# How can I connect to storage queue using Azure AD and WebJobs SDK?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-webjobs, azure-storage-queues, azure-rbac

My WebJobs app uses an Azure Storage Queue Trigger. It runs smoothly when the connection string to the storage account the queue app listens to is set-up in the configuration; i.e. appsettings.json.

```
{ "AzureWebJobsStorage": "connString" }
```

However, I do not want to expose any secrets in the configuration and more importantly,  I'd like to avoid access keys altogether, relying on Azure AD and role-based access control (RBAC) instead.

For this, I have assigned the service principal running the application the [Queue Data Contributor Role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-queue-data-contributor) and switched in the connectivity type of the queue from `Access key` to `Azure AD` in the portal.

My intent was to use the [Azure Identity SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.identity?WT.mc_id=ondotnet-c9-cephilli) and new-up an instance of `DefaultAzureCredential` and use that to connect my app to the queue.

But as far as I can see, the Webjobs SDK expects to connect using acres key, i.e. a connection string. When using the standalone storage queue client, this is straightforward, since I can create the queue client using above-mentioned Identity SDK. However in WebJobs it seems I cannot override the means of connecting to that queue.

How can I access that queue via Azure AD and RBAC? Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the bindings used with the WebJobs SDK do not support using the identity SDK.

Instead, you could store the connection string in KeyVault and use the [KeyVault References feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references) which relies on [Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet) to fetch the secret from KeyVault at runtime.

Directly using the respective client SDK would be the way to go otherwise.